How to use Container.image.src and Container.image.fit instead of image_src?
In Flet of Python that uses Flutter UI controls, I used the image_src and image_fit but my terminal says they are deprecated.
ft.Container(
                    expand=3,
                    image_src="assets/splash.png",
                    image_fit="cover",
                    content=ft.Column(
                        alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        controls=[
                            ft.Icon(ft.icons.LOCK_PERSON_ROUNDED, size=100),
                            ft.Text(
                                "Welcome Back",
                                color=ft.colors.BLUE_900,
                                size=40,
                                weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ),

Do you have some example using Container.image.src and Container.image.fit? So far, my program works but I have these warnings:
_src is deprecated since version 0.24.0 and will be removed in version 0.27.0. Use Container.image.src instead.
_fit is deprecated since version 0.24.0 and will be removed in version 0.27.0. Use Container.image.fit instead.
  self.image_fit = image_fit

I'm new to Flet after coming from customtkinter and beeware.
I tried
ft.Container(
                    expand=3,
                    # image_src="assets/splash.png",
                    # image_fit="cover",
                    image=ft.Image(
                        src="assets/splash.png",
                        fit="cover"
                    ),
                    content=ft.Column(
                        alignment=ft.MainAxisAlignment.CENTER,
                        controls=[
                            ft.Icon(ft.icons.LOCK_PERSON_ROUNDED, size=100),
                            ft.Text(
                                "Welcome to EyeQSoft",
                                color=ft.colors.BLUE_900,
                                size=40,
                                weight=ft.FontWeight.BOLD,
                            )
                        ]
                    )
                ),

but the
image=ft.Image(
                 src="assets/splash.png",
                 fit="cover"
              ),

does not show the image.

For me it worked that way:
image=ft.DecorationImage(
    src='assets/splash.png',
    fit=ft.ImageFit.COVER,
)


It worked. Thank you!
